# How to make where clause optional with ORM?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a query:

```
User.includes(:translations, :user_roles, :user_rating,
                              :user_verification, :portfolios, :reviews, :user_account,
                              :task_responses, :user_favorite_categories, :photo)
                    .where(
                      user_favorite_categories: { category: cat&.main_category_ids },
                      user_reviews: { review_type: 'author_as_contractor' }
                    )
                    .where('users.hidden_until is null OR users.hidden_until < ?', Time.current)
```

This query includes user's reviews

How to make `user_reviews: { review_type: 'author_as_contractor' }` clause optional?

Select user even if he has no reviews.

Comment: Easy, just remove it.  Get rid of that where clause and add "user_reviews" to your includes statement so you can query records as needed efficiently later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eager_load` and `where` like this for that:

```rb
User.eager_load(:reviews)
    .where(user_reviews: { review_type: ['author_as_contractor', nil] })
```